# numberOfLines in ios 9.1

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

Did the application, testing all the functionality in the iphone 5s emulator with the version of ios 11.2.

Everything was fine, but decided to test the application on iOS 9.1 and eventually found a strange bug. This screenshot screenshot on version 11.2:

[image]

And this is on version 9.1:
[image]

As you can see, ios 9.2 displays only one line of text, and in all parts of the program. UILabel is described everywhere the same way and looks like:

```
let titlePost: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold)
    label.numberOfLines = 0

    return label
}()
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: I noticed that when json is loaded into my title everything is fine. Problems begin when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    titlePost.sizeToFit()
    shortContentPost.sizeToFit()
}
```

This solved the problem